# How to cancel schedule notification

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase

I'm using react-native-firebase: 5.5.6 and react-native:0.59.10 on my project. I've created some schedule notifications. When i try to cancel some of them, that's not worked.

```
cancelNotification = async (Id) => {
    try{
        await firebase.notifications().cancelNotification(Id);
    }
    catch(e){
    console.error(e);
    }
}
```

I don't know where the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function "firebase.notifications().cancelNotification(id)" return a Promise,
Do u use it with an await ? like this :

```js
async YourFunction(){
  try{
  const cancel = await firebase.notifications().cancelNotification(id);
  console.log(cancel)
  }
  catch(e){
  console.error(e)
  }
}
```

U can now see what is happen in your log,
Hope it will help

Comment: It not works only if put an interval time. As i tested it, if i add an interval time example by "minute", after some notifications i decide to delete it, but notifications keep coming in interval by 1 minute.

Comment: Should i use removeDeliveredNotification(id) for that case ?